# Emulate Git repo in JUnit

Tags: java, git, testing, junit, mocking

In a recent project I have the need to test a Java class that makes use of a specific Git repository. For the class to work it has to take a path to the repository and then do its magic.

What I'm interested in is whether it is possible to emulate a Git repository in JUnit, or by any other means provide a mock repository with which the class could be tested.

Using an actual Git repository dedicated to this tests would be an option, but because of the nature of the environment it could be difficult to ensure that the tests could be run from every machine that another developer may use to run the tests. Furthermore the actual repository isn't small and it would take at least 10 minutes to clone it.

So far I wasn't able to find any way to emulate a repository with maybe 10 - 15 commits inside a JUnit test class so every suggestion is welcome.

Oh yes, the repository would ideally also have multiple subrepositories/submodules, but I would also be happy with a solution that provides a single repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of advices:

1. **Is it possible to include your repository part of test resources?**

   - In that case you will not have to clone it over and over again.
2. **There are higher level Java APIs to manipulate with git repositories.**

   - Look at the [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/).

Comment: We are using JGit for querying the repo, but the idea was to test the methods and classes that rely on the repo that we access through JGit.

Unfortunately the repo is too big to be added as a test resource.

For now we've settled with a lot of mocking and stubing of some of the method responses, but now we have a separate issue that's addressed in a few other questions.